# How to add days to a DateTime variable with custom format

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using two DateTime Pickers each with a custom format "dd-MMM-yy"
I try to add one day to them but it isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
DateTime current = from_txt.value;
current.AddDays(1);
```

DateTime Picker from_txt properties.

```
custom format = "dd-MMM-yy"
Format = custom format
```

I want to add one day as I said before without changing the format. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the format have to do with adding a day to it? What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: Please, note that `current.AddDays(1);` adds one day and then *throws away* the result

Comment: Do this: `var current = DateTime.ParseExact(from_txt.value, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @DavidConrad Not working means days are not getting added. I used MessageBox to display current. There I noticed that the date remained same throughout. Hope now you understood my problem. :(

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes I noticed that. so I did this : `current = current.AddDays(1);` Now my problem is rectified. I sincerely thank eveyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the days you have to save that in another variable. As clearly stated above, the `AddDays()` method throws away that value.

We can do this :-

```
DateTime new_date = current.AddDays(1);
```

The `new_date` variable  will have the incremented value.